# Way to fix picture dates (in the future) taken on WhatsApp in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, photos, whatsapp.app

In the last few days (prob. after updating to iOS 10) some pictures I take keep having dates in the future. (See screenshot below.)

**EDIT 1:** All pictures before and after the faulty ones - even by a matter of seconds - have the correct time and place. In the image below, you can see at the top pictures taken this morning with the proper location (blurred out) and the right times.

**EDIT 2:** all pictures having this issue were taken within WhatsApp, but at least the last picture taken in the app had the correct date and time, but no location. (The app is allowed to use my location when it's in use.)

Any idea why this is happening or how to fix this?

[image: Sep. 22 and 24 dates, even though it's September 18]

Comment: Have you verified your iPhone's time and date settings are correct?  Do you allow Photos to access your location so that it knows when & where the photo was taken?

Comment: @fbara thanks! I have - they're automatically set and working fine in all but some pictures. All pictures or even screenshots taken right after or before (by a matter of seconds) the faulty ones are well placed in time and space.

Comment: So it's not all pictures/screenshots are incorrect, it's only some of the pictures/screenshots?  Are you modifying the images in some way and then the date/time are incorrect?

Comment: Yes! Taken with whatsapp, turns out. Editing question.